# Google manual seach - how to filter by year

Tags: google-chrome

When manually searching using Google engine, how can I get results only from the past year/month etc?

Answer (score 0):

[Advanced search](https://www.google.com/advanced_search). `last update:` field.

[image: Screenshot]